# Invalid Swagger Security Definition

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

can someone please help me with my swagger definition?
It gets created by swashbuckle (C#) but something is wrong in the security definition part

```
`"securityDefinitions": {
"oauth2": {
"type":"oauth2",
"flow":"implicit",
"authorizationUrl":"https://myserver/core/connect/authorize",
"tokenUrl":"https://myserver/core/connect/token",
"scopes":{ 
"scopeOne":"Allows access to the service",
"scopeTwo":"Allows access to the service"
}
},
"apiKey":{
"name":"ApiKey",
"in":"header",
"type":"apiKey"
}
}`
```

The validation error is:

> Error: Swagger schema validation failed. 
>           Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf' at #/securityDefinitions/oauth2
>
> Additional properties not allowed: scopes,tokenUrl,authorizationUrl,flow at #/securityDefinitions/oauth2
>
> Missing required property: in at #/securityDefinitions/oauth2
>
> Additional properties not allowed: tokenUrl at #/securityDefinitions/oauth2
>
> Additional properties not allowed: authorizationUrl at #/securityDefinitions/oauth2
>
> Additional properties not allowed: authorizationUrl at #/securityDefinitions/oauth2
>
> No enum match for: implicit at #/securityDefinitions/oauth2/flow

Comment: Where did you get the validation error? from https://editor.swagger.io?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: OK. As a workaround, please copy the securityDefinitions from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L561 and modify to suit your needs.

Comment: I don't see any differences I have the same attributes as in the example

Comment: I couldn't see any difference either, that's why I suggested copying that and modify to suit your needs.

Comment: The petstore spec posted by William also doesn't validate using Big Stick Carpet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tokenUrl seems to be an invalid parameter..

Comment: To elaborate on this answer: Once I removed the invalid parameters it worked.